# Shrink and Transform UIButton

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton, animatewithduration

I am trying to transform my `UIButton` left when clicked, and I want it to shrink at the same time as well. I have tried the following code, and it does transform left, but I do not know how to shrink the button. How could I shrink and transform the `UIButton`.

```
@IBAction func joinCircleButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let button = sender as UIButton

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{
        button.frame = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x - 75, button.frame.origin.y,button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height)
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this code inside your animation block. Which scale the button to half of its size.

```
button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: That works thanks. But when I click on it a second time, it just goes off the screen. How would I prevent it from going off the screen?

Comment: Each time the button is shift left by 75 points, you should check `button.frame.origin.x - 75` to see if it is greater than 0.